# How to prevent deleting missing layers in qgis

Tags: qgis, layers

When I open a project containing WMS layers while the internet connection is off, I get a message that the layers will be removed from the project.

I can choose a new source or confirm it and lose the layers.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

Install the "changeDataSource" plugin. One of the features this plugin offers is that missing layers aren't automatically removed from a project.

Comment: @Archi if the answer helped you to solve your problem, please accept it.